# How to use JavaScript to make the HTML page link somewhere else

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

In JavaScript, I have a switch statement, and depending on which case is true, I need the HTML page to link somewhere else, so each case has a different link in it. I haven't found anything on this online, and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the html page to link somewhere"?  Are you trying to do this when a user clicks on a link?

Comment: no, it's when the push a submit button

Comment: Do you want the form to submit to another page or just have them be redirected?

Comment: I don't know what the difference is between those two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of what you have tried would be most useful. Anyway - here goes... a contrived example:

```
function go_somewhere(expr) {
    var somewhere = "";
    switch (expr) {
        case "home":
            somewhere = "http://www.home.com";
            break;
        case "away":
            somewhere = "http://www.away.com";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    window.location.href = somewhere;
}
```

Comment: `window's` `location` is an object, you need to assign the string to the `.href` property: `window.location.href = somewhere`

Answer (score -1):

You can write some function that gets called when the user clicks on the link.

And then do the easy and standard

```
location.href = newUrl;
```

Comment: I'm kind of new to programming, and I don't exactly know what you mean

Comment: I think you meant `location.href = newUrl;`